# EM Wave equation and dispersion in a plasma

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am currently studying for qualifiers and I am really stuck on this one practice problem and I want to understand why I am having such a difficult time.

The idea is that we have a plasma with free electron density $n$, and this induces a current density $J$.  From this I want to find:

1) a wave equation

2) an expression for $\frac{dJ}{dt}$ and

3) assuming a solution $\exp{(i kz-wt)} \hat{ x},$ find a dispersion relation.

My approach:  Maxwell's Equations.  Specifically taking the curl of 
$\nabla \times E$
$$
\nabla \times(\nabla\times E=-\partial B/\partial t)
$$
$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot E)-\nabla^2E=-\partial/\partial t (\mu_0J+\mu_0\epsilon_0\partial E/\partial t)$$
$$\nabla^2E-\nabla(\rho/\epsilon_0)=\mu_0 (\partial J/\partial t+\partial^2E/\partial t^2)$$
So that is what I have solved as my wave equation.  However, I believe that $\rho$ is simply $n$ (only charge available, so my intuition tells me that $\nabla \rho=0$.  This would reduce it slightly to something that looks more like a wave equation to me.

The second part asks for an expression $\frac{dJ}{dt}$ using Newton's second law with a coulomb force.  So I go about:

$$F=ma=m(dv/dt)=qE$$
$$qm\dot v=q^2E\implies q\dot v=\frac{q^2}{m}E=AdJ/dt$$
$$dJ/dt = \frac{q^2}{mA}E$$
This is where I feel I may have made a mistake.  I know Ohms law tells us that $J=\sigma E$ so I believe that $\dot J$~$\dot E$.  Have I thought about this correctly, in that $q\dot v= AJ$ , where A is the cross sectional area.

I am not really sure if I am approaching this properly.  I think once I have these two down, then the dispersion question should be simple, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is solved correctly. The second part, I guess is more complicated. Assuming motion of electrons under an applied alternating field, by Newton's laws,

$$ m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + m\gamma \dfrac{dx}{dt} + {\omega_0}^2 x= qE_0 \cos\omega t$$

EDIT: The question requires $\gamma$, $\omega$ both going to zero.

from which you can find out that the time dependent solution for $x$ is proportional to $E_0\exp(-i\omega t)\;.$

Now by definition,
$$ J = Nqv$$

So differentiating $v = \dfrac{dx}{dt} $, you get

$$ J = \sigma E$$

Notice that $\sigma$ here is a complex quantity unlike the case of conductors.

Comment: Am I correct in that del p=0

Comment: @yankeefan11 it has to be as charge cannot accumulate inside plasma.

Comment: I get that.  So for the second part, we are assumed to ignore the $\gamma$ effects., so it is just m(dv/dt)=qE(r,t).  And because J=Nqv, dJ/dt=Nq(dv/dt), which means that $dJ/dt=\frac{NE(r,t)q^2}{m}$ if I am correct?

Comment: @yankeefan11 i got that. I got an incorrect term in my answer which I edited just now. Please see it. The answer will be clear.

Comment: So will the $\omega_0^2$ impact that at all?

Comment: @yankeefan11 it will and even in the limit of neglecting $\gamma$, it will give the same solution as I have mentioned in the answer. try it out.

Comment: Wait.  Why is there a restoring kx force.  The plasma is free electrons, we are not making a SHO approximation

Comment: You can choose $\omega_0$ to be zero too. But what matters is that the electric field here is an oscillating function that you didn't put in. Now you can solve for $x$ easily and show that $J = \sigma E$

Comment: I'd like to add that there *can* be non-zero charge inside a plasma. The necessary condition for something to be a plasma is that it is *quasi-neutral*, meaning that when averaging over large scales, there are equally many positive and negative charges. On scales comparable to the Debye length, however, there can be a displacement between electron "clouds" and ion "clouds". This is the case in for instance electron plasma waves. By the way, for ion-electron (i-e) plasma, $\rho=q_e n_e + q_i n_i$, and $\mathbf J=q_e n_e \mathbf v_e + q_i n_i \mathbf v_i$.